# How to know if my iPhone has spyware

Tags: mobile, ios, spyware

Is there a way I can check if my phone is being tapped or monitored by a spy app? I’ve updated security patches but I am still not ok with that. Any advice?

Comment: Hi and welcome on Security SE. As a typical user, there's not much more that you can do. Apple's app store is pretty well curated. To what extend you are willing to go for examination? As it stands, I consider this question too broad. Are you in a specific target group? Are you concerned about a specific attack scenario?

Comment: Thank you for your response. One of my coworker basically hacked into my phone, recording my online activities and calls. He is a tech savvy person. I don’t know what to do.

Comment: @Quetitude In this case I would suggest you do a complete factory reset. However I would more think of that they hacked themselves into the iCloud. Most stuff is snynchronized into it. But I am not an apple person. Maybe you ask specific questions about this on the respective SE site.